# How to get paypal account type Rest Api?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using route /v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo to get user`s account info after they login by paypal. But i need to get their account_type to restrict using personal accounts on my platform.

i tried to use another route v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo but result is the same (there is no account_type info)

Comment: Consider including the code section applicable to your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem - I wish I could close the PayPal documentation for lack of detail or clarity!!! So rubbish it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That information is not returned by the Log in with PayPal integration and identity APIs.

Perhaps you are looking for [Seller Onboarding](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/).